# I'm looking for an alternative to this Infinite Loop

Tags: java, switch-statement, infinite-loop

I'm using a while(true) loop for the below code but we've been stopped from using it. I can't think of another way of doing this.

I've tried using a do-while loop but it doesn't help my situation here.

'''java

```
while(true){
            System.out.println("\nSelect the number of the Option you wish to carry out:\n    1) Enter Scores\n    2) Find Golfer\n    3) Display Scoreboard\n    4) Edit Scoresheet\n    5) Exit\n ");
            userChoice = integerVerify(); //Used to verify whether user input is a valid number
            switch (userChoice) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter the scores in the following order");
                    displayPlayers();   //Displays scoreboard to help users enter player scores in order.
                    addScores();    //Used to verify whether user input is a valid String
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("**********PLEASE ENTER THE NAME OF THE PLAYER YOU WISH TO FIND**********");
                    findPlayer();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    displayPlayers();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    options();
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Are you sure you wish to exit?");
                    confirm = stringVerify();
                    if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        System.out.println("Thank you for using our application.");
                        System.out.println("Exiting");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Please enter an appropriate option.");
            }
        }
```

'''

The code needs to reject anything that's not in the switch-case...but it also needs to display an appropriate message whether it be through a function or from within the loop itself and ultimately, I still need it to loop until the exit option (case 5) is entered.

Comment: Why is `while(true)` not allowed? This looks like a valid scenario for using it. You could use `for(;;)` if it is just a case of not allowing `while`

Comment: It's for an assignment. They're trying to make us use more appropriate ways of carrying out a loop. But I might stick with it regardless since it seems to be the more appropriate way of doing it

Comment: I'm not sure how to make recursion work here.  A top level control loop in this kind of an app is very common, what you did was pretty good.  If you want extra credit with your teacher you might replace the numbers with numeric constants as in "case DISPLAY:" and "case EXIT:" for readability.

Comment: You could make the menu a function and call it once in the main method, once in the default case and then once again after the switch.  This should make it inescapable until such time where the program is closed manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most long running systems have a top level "Infinite" loop of some sort.  I don't see a huge problem with this, but politically some people don't like infinite loops.

If that's your problem, initialize a Boolean "running" flag to true, use while(running) and instead of System.exit() set running to false.  Should be the same effect.

```
public static void main(String[] s)
{
    Boolean running=true;
    while(running) {        
         switch() {
         ...
             case 5:
               ...
                if(exitConditionsMet) 
                    running=false;
          …
          }         
     }
     return; // Just let main return to exit program.
 }
```

Technically there is no real difference, but some people have been trained to scan for that while(true) construct and call it a problem.

There are a couple SLIGHT advantages to the flag approach...

- The control flow of exiting through a function is unexpected.  If you were scanning that code at a very high level just looking for flow control (braces and if/while/for/break type constructs), you wouldn't immediately see that that loop would ever exit.
- Some static analysis tools might be slightly confused for the same reason.
- System.exit should generally be avoided (as a matter of habit, not in this case specifically).  System.exit can force containers (like Tomcat) to shut down unnaturally, it can also kill threads that might be in the middle of doing something important (Except when you need to return a value to the command line which means you need a system.exit() but probably want to make it the last line of your main.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bill. But I was thinking, what about using recursive functions? Wouldn't this fix the whole problem of the loop??